# How to write composition of epimorphisms

Tags: math-mode, align

I am trying to write the following composition of epimorphisms, but I don't like the form. 
[image]

The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\newcommand{\rightarrowdbl}{\rightarrow\mathrel{\mkern-14mu}\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\xrightarrowdbl}[2][]{%
  \xrightarrow[#1]{#2}\mathrel{\mkern-14mu}\rightarrow}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\phi \circ \pi: \mathbb{Z}[X] & \xrightarrowdbl{\ \pi \ } \mathbb{Z}_2[X] && \xrightarrowdbl{\ \phi \ }  \mathbb{Z}_2,\\
f(X) & \longmapsto \pi (f(X)):=\overline{f(X)} && \longmapsto  \phi(\overline{f(X)}):=\overline{f(0)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to write it?

Thank you!

Comment: First I will change `:=` with `\mathrel{\mathop:}=`. What exactly are you interested in changing? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for your comment.  I just wonder if there is a another way to improve the format. For example to reduce the gap in the second ring epimorphism. Any ideas please?

Comment: Don't worry. My english language is very poor. What do you mean "to reduce the gap in the second ring"? Can you explain me with simple language what do you do? Is it correct in English. Generally for commutative-diagrams I use the package `tikz-cd` or `xy` and the translator (now no :-(),

Comment: Chris peraphs I have understood. Can I have a little time, please?

Comment: You can remove the white space between `\overline{f(X)}` and `\longmapsto` by using `\begin{alignat*}{2}` instead of `\begin{align*}` (and the corresponding end). But it's bad nonetheless.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your comment. As you said, I m not sure is this is really useful. Do you have another idea?

Comment: @Chris Not trying to align those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will chose for to draw your composition of epimorphisms, the classic package to create commutative diagrams: [`tikz-cd`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf).

The use of [`tikz-cd`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) it makes the reading of switching diagrams better as the picture shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm]
{\phi \circ \pi: \mathbb{Z}[X]} \arrow[r, "\pi", two heads] & {\mathbb{Z}_2[X]} \arrow[r, "\phi", two heads] & \mathbb{Z}_2 
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1cm, column sep=.5cm]
f(X)   \arrow[r, maps to] & \pi (f(X))\mathrel{\mathop:}=\overline{f(X)} \arrow[r, maps to] & \phi(\overline{f(X)})\mathrel{\mathop:}=\overline{f(0)}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You ve got it! I had something like that in my mind, thank you! (your English are ok, so don't worry) Thank you very much.

Comment: @Chris I am happy to help you. My best regards.

Comment: Let me ask you something more. What if we had monomorphisms or isomorphisms? Which will be the format?

Comment: @Chris You're welcome. As this link: https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/jonasf/80-514-814/hw/hw2.tex

Comment: @Chris The tikz-cd is often used in this case. Same for the isomorphisms.